# Exclude users from belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel

I have User model and belongsToMany thumbs relation.

Using L5 repository, I want to have Criteria that will exclude all users from thumb_id. How to do this?

My user has id 1.

user_thumbs table looks like this.

```
user_id, thumb_id
1        2
```

When I GET /users I want to display all users except user with id 2.

```
return $model->whereDoesntHave('thumbs', function ($q) {
   $q->where('user_thumbs.user_id', $this->userId);
});
```

```
public function thumbs()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_thumbs', 'user_id', 'thumb_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
}
```

With this approach, I exclude just my user, but all others are present.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Using L5 repository, I want to have Criteria that will exclude all users from thumb_id. How to do this?